# First X that cannot be expressed as a sum of integer numbers in a list

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Given N and random N numbers (the numbers could appear more than once), which is the first $X$ that cannot be expressed as a sum of at least one subsequence? The subsequences may not overlap.

Examples:

$N=2; A=\{1, 1\}; Ans=3$

$N=3;A=\{1, 2, 2\};Ans=6$

$N=1;A=\{2\};Ans=1$

Comment: Presumably we're talking about nonnegative integers.  Enumerate all possible sums, and see what's the first missing number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about positive integers, and $A$ is given as a non-decreasing sequence, then $X$ can be found in $O(N)$ operations. Let $A=\langle A_0,\ldots,A_{N-1}\rangle$ with $A_0\leqslant\ldots\leqslant A_{N-1}$, and put $A_N=\infty$ (for convenience). Next, let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_k$ for $0\leqslant n\leqslant N$ (so that $S_0=0$) and
$$m=\min\{n : 0\leqslant n\leqslant N, S_n+1<A_n\}.$$
Then $\color{blue}{X=S_m+1}$ (to see this, prove by induction on $k$, $0\leqslant k\leqslant m$, that each number between $1$ and $S_k$ inclusive (if any, as we include $k=0$) is a sum of some subsequence of $A$).